# Open source C# projects with both unit tests and mocks (not MVC projects)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, mocking, rhino-mocks

I would like to know of any prominent projects in Codeplex, GitHub etc which are C# with ASP.NET or even just C# APIs with both functioning tests (NUnit) and mocks (RhinoMocks, NMock etc).

The emphasis is on both tests and mocks.

Answer (score 1):

look at [AutoMapper project](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)

This is not ASP.NET but good for investigate Unit tests

Answer (score 0):

You said not MVC projects, but is the actual [ASP.NET MVC framework](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41742) ok?

Its got a few thousand tests, and uses mocking extensively.

Aside from that, NHibernate, Sharp Architecture, FluentNHiberante etc have pretty good unit tests and mocks.